# How do I extrude a vertex group in Python, the same way that the 'E' shortcut does it

Tags: python, geometry, extrude

Been smashing my head against this all day. When I select a vertex group and press <kbd>E</kbd> on the keyboard, I am able to extrude the selection to a locked axis/direction that is in line with the geometry.

How can I do this in Python?

I made a quick video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5fW5Ug2ZPU&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to reproduce operations in python is by using the the info editor.
In this case i first executed the "extrude-region" in edit mode and copied the info log to my python script.

[image]

Comment: If I do this and copy the exact line of code and run it from my script, it doesn't seem to reproduce the same thing I get when I run the tool manually.

Comment: It should if you have the same selection. Otherwise you could always go in and tweak the parameters. I think they are named in an understandable way, so "[..] TRANSFORM_OT_translator={"value":(0, 0, 0.8), [...]" for example does the amout of extrusion.

Comment: If your usecase is more special, i could take a look at your file, if you want.

Comment: Weirdly, it started working this morning after I posted!! Cheers dude. I think I've got it from here.

Comment: Glad too hear that! I good night sleep can fix many things xD